# convert js to coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript, datatables

My question is how would I would convert the following javascript to coffeescript for a rails project using datatables:

```
$.extend( $.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {
  "sWrapper": "dataTables_wrapper form-inline"
} );
```

... this works:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#logs').dataTable
    bJQueryUI: true
    sDom: "<'row'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>"
    sPaginationType: "full_numbers"
    oLanguage: "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
```

The $.extend javascript is from the DataTables web site that's needed to 
use Twitter Bootstrap with DataTables, and I just can't figure out how 
to convert that to coffeescript.

**Update**:
For anyone encountering this issue, just use the gem "jquery-datatables-rails" 
which makes it easy to include DataTables in a Rails app and it supports 
Twitter Bootstrap.

Comment: Usually coffeescript doesn't have the "{}" or semi-colons, I thought.

Comment: What have you tried? Which part(s) are unclear? "Not a real question" as it is. (There are a number of constructs in there, *which one* is the question about?)

Comment: I've answered but also voted to close (does that make any sense?). Just go to http://js2coffee.org/

Comment: Really for me gem "jquery-datatables-rails" does not work with bootstrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use http://js2coffee.org/ when in doubt.

This would be the obvious (the braces are optional):

```
$.extend $.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {
  sWrapper: "dataTables_wrapper form-inline"
}
```

Some people would do this, which I think goes too far, it's confusing:

```
$.extend(
  $.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses
  sWrapper: "dataTables_wrapper form-inline"
)
```

Personally I prefer to remove complexity from function calls:

```
wrapperOptions =
    sWrapper: "dataTables_wrapper form-inline"

jQuery.extend $.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, wrapperOptions
```